# Is necessary put "add_index" in a migration one to many?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, relational-database

For example in this migration I have a relation one to many "Category has many Subcategories". If I not put "add_index :subcategories, :category_id", it work anyway.

```
class CreateSubcategories < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :subcategories do |t|
      t.string :nombre
      t.string :descripcion
      t.integer :category_id

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :subcategories, :category_id
  end
end
```

For validate foreign key I use this

```
validates :category, presence: true
```

Answer (score 1):

Its advised to add index on such a column as supposedly you will be performing multiple lookups across the two tables.  In relational database, column `category_id` would be a foreign key on `subcategories` table which references `id` column of `category` table.  You'll find more information on [Database index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index) at wikipedia (quickest available reference).

Sure, you could skip creating index for this column but for a performance penalty eventually.  Sure it would work without index but I believe you also want an application that is good usability wise - usability in terms of performance.  When your table grows large(theoretically), you'll eventually start noticing that Data Retrieval involving joins across two or more tables, `categories` and `subcategories` in this case relatively slower.

Sure, one can argue that there is a performance penalty for maintaining an index, i.e. the DBMS would have to go through extra writes.  So, it is really up to you and your business requirement whether or not you have more number of Data retrievals or Data writes.  If you have more data retrievals then definitely go for the index, if you think there won't be much reads and only writes which you feel your application can live with (less likely) then sure you could skip it.

Given the scenario where you're performing validations on the `category`'s presence.  I would definitely go with adding the index.